# Why is the Azure repo branch defaulting to main instead of master?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have created a new repository in azure repos and the branch name is defaulting as "main", whereas my expectation is it should have been master.

Please explain if someone knows the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently default branch name was changed from `master` to `main`. Please check it [here - Azure Repos default branch name](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-repos-default-branch-name/)

> What if I want to keep using master?
>
> If you prefer not to change, you should enable this feature and set master as your preferred branch name. Then, when the default changes to main, your repositories will continue to use master.

But you can change it here:

[image]